# (null): iPad: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, architecture, error-handling

When I build my iphone app and my ipad app for archiving, I get this message: (But with iPhone instead of iPad in the iPhone app ofc)

```
(null):  iPad: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)
```

I didn't get this error before! I didn't get it for my free versions of my app (which is almost the same code) I think it has something to do with iPhone 5? I want it to work with iPhone 5 so I don't want to remove it armv7s

/A noob

Comment: Which iOS version are you targeting? 
If it's earlier than 4.1, try updating it to 4.1.

Comment: I think that warning is perfectly normal, check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait until all custom libs in your project will update. Check it, some of popular libs have updated yet.

Until that remove armv7s:

Project -> Build Settings -> Archetecures

Comment: Hmm how to remove them? :S It says "armv7, armv7s $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)" And there is no other options

Comment: You can choose "Other..." -> "+" -> "armv7"

Comment: Hm there is no option "armv7" but I'll try to write it myself?
It takes forever to build it, for some reason..

Comment: Yes, write it yourself. I just wrote armv7 to solve this problem.

Comment: Now it is finally done... and I got an error saying that the armv7 is the same as another file or something :S

Comment: Wow, that's really strange... Is this file from custom lib? Did this issue appeare after xcode and sdk update?

Comment: No I don't think so? :p It appeared yesterday, but I was able to build it after the update, before this error :P 
Anyway, I changed the "Valid architectures" instead, and then it worked with the iPad app.. It is now uploaded...
The warning disappeared from the iPhone app aswell, but now I can't reach the .app file (it's red)... Guess it doesn't build properly

Comment: " wait until all custom libs in your project will update" -- what does this mean? I've got a custom lib in my project, and it has always worked, but now Apple won't allow submission to app store because of this (which is insane - if app is going to run on both archs, why can't it have both archs?)

Answer (score 10):

This warning is perfectly normal when you use an armv7 device to archive your application.

Think about it, you make an archive that includes the armv7s architecture (which is what we want) and the warning tells you that your armv7 device does not support that architecture (which totally makes sense).

To prove that even further, just hook up an iPhone 5 and try archiving and you will see that the warning will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on the XCode 4.6.3.
I get message:

```
iPhone/iPod: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): i386
```

it turned out that if before the Build,  run an application on the simulator, the application is going to the architecture i386 (for Mac), ignoring the Project Settings. Before Build need choose iOS Device as target.